# How do I get the External IP of a Kubernetes service as a raw value?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, google-kubernetes-engine

I am running an application with GKE. It works fine but I can not figure out how to get the external IP of the service in a machine readable format.
So i am searching a gcloud or kubectl command that gives me only the external IP or a url of the format `http://192.168.0.2:80` so that I can cut out the IP.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe not GKE as my clusters are on AWS, but I assume logic will be similar. When you `kubectl get svc` you can select output format and it will show more then just the "normal" get. For me, with ELB based services to het LB hostname it's enough to run ie. `kubectl -n kube-system get svc cluster-nginx-ingress-controller -o json | jq .status.loadBalancer.ingress.hostname`

Comment: Note: use `-r` on the jq to get the raw value if you want to use it elsewhere (otherwise it includes the quotes in the string it returns)

Comment: I prefer using `jsonpath`
`kubectl get services -l component=controller,app=nginx-ingress -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].hostname}"`

Comment: This gave me an error of `Cannot index array with string "hostname"`, instead I used `jq -r ".status.loadBalancer.ingress | .[].ip"`

Answer (score 22):

You can use the [jsonpath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) output type to get the data directly without needing the additional `jq` to process the json:

```bash
kubectl get services \
   --namespace ingress-nginx \
   nginx-ingress-controller \
   --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}'
```

##### NOTE

Be sure to replace the namespace and service name, respectively, with yours.

Answer (score 6):

In my case '*kubectl get services*' returns array of items, but not just one service.

So then such jsonpath works fine to me:

```
kubectl get services -l component=controller,app=nginx-ingress -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
```

Answer (score 2):

The answers above do not provide the output the user asked. The correct command would be:
`kubectl -n $namespace get svc $ingressServiceName -o json | jq -r .status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname`

Comment: My two cents: some terminals (like mine running on Mac OS) require single quotes to do the match, otherwise it can't find it

kubectl -n default get svc my-service-name -o json  | jq -r '.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].hostname'

Answer (score 2):

...and yet another way... This will list *all* the "load-balancer" services

`kubectl get services --all-namespaces -o json | jq -r '.items[] | { name: .metadata.name, ns: .metadata.namespace, ip: .status.loadBalancer?|.ingress[]?|.ip  }'`

Depending on the networkPlugin used by your cluster services/pods may be exposed directly on external-ip. But this will also find an Ingress controllers run in the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

To get the external-ip on GCP i can use:

```
kubectl get services --namespace=<your-namespace> -o jsonpath="{.items[0].status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
```

Answer (score 0):

All previous solutions don't work any more for me (on GCP).

To get the IP:

```sh
kubectl get ingress <YOUR_INGRESS_NAME> -o jsonpath="{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}"
```

To get the host-name:

```sh
kubectl get ingress <YOUR_INGRESS_NAME> -o jsonpath="{.spec.rules[0].host}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
minikube tunnel
```

or

```
kubectl cluster-info
```

You can get the public exposed IP of your relevant service.